# For INSERT, using LIKE statement with a variable

Tags: python, mysql, sql

How would I properly write the following INSERT using LIKE?

```
provider = provider
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO raw_financials (provider, vendor_id) 
                  VALUES (%s, %s)""", 
                 ((SELECT provider FROM main_app_provider 
                   WHERE provider LIKE %s%, %provider), vendor_id)
```

For example, with the above LIKE statement, "Apple" would match "Apple Inc.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM` variant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) of the INSERT command:

```
sql = """
    INSERT INTO raw_financials (provider, vendor_id)
    SELECT provider, %s
    FROM main_app_provider
    WHERE provider LIKE %s
    """ 
args = (vendor_id, '%'+provider+'%')
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```